# Question regarding allocating memory for array, sorting and numbers only in C programming

Tags: c, arrays, linux, sorting

I have a program that I would like to dynamically allocate an array that gets filled by the user through the terminal argument line in Linux. After the user enters the numbers, the array of numbers should be sorted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int i;
    int array[100];
    int count = 0;
    while(1){
        printf("please enter a number: \n");
        scanf("%d", &i);
        if(i == 0){
            for (int k = 0; k < count -1; k++) {
                    if(array[k] <= array[k + 1]){
                    int temp = array[k];
                    array[k] = array[k+1];
                    array[k+1] = temp;
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j)
            {
                printf("%d ", array[j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            break;
        } else {
                array[count] = i;
                count++;
        }
    }       
}
```

This only sorts the array if I type the numbers in low to high, but if I enter the numbers from high to low eg. 4, 3, 2 and then 1, it prints 2, 3, 1 and then 4, instead of the 1,2,3,4 that it does if I type it that way.
I don't want to initialize the array with 100, I just can't get it to work if I don't initialize it. I want it to be increased if necessary.

Thank you :)

Comment: You are not giving any value to the array to sort (as intended from command line arguments) & array has not been dynamically allocated in this.

Comment: You cannot get an automatically resizing array in C, you have to write the code for it yourself (e.g.: using `malloc` and `realloc`)

Comment: You have to add something to your code to make sort algorithm, now you only iterate once for array and swapping elements - it is not enough to sort all items.

Comment: You can use linked list data structure

Comment: You have one pass of a [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) in this code. That isn't going to cut it if you want to sort previously unsorted data.There should be as many passes as required to sort the array.

Comment: For dynamic allocation initialize like `int *array = NULL; size_t arraysize = 0;` then after reading a new number add one new element `array = realloc((arraysize + 1) * sizeof(*array)); array[arraysize] = i; arraysize++;` and at the end of your program `free(array)`. For sorting just `qsort(array, arraysize, sizeof(*array), compare_two_ints);` where `int compare_two_ints(const void *a, const void *b) { const int *x = a, *y = b; return *x - *y; }`

Answer (score 1):

**Errors/Deviations from the proposed program:**

- As mentioned, you want to use command line arguments - You need `main(argc,*argv[])` instead of `main()`.
- For dynamic allocation you need `malloc/calloc` but instead of that you have used static array.
- Your code shows you are not clear about concept of sorting, leave the program aside and use a pen and paper first to clear that.